# How is "restore purchase" actually implemented in most apps?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

According to Apple [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/restoring_purchased_products), calling `restoreCompletedTransactions()` prompts user for App Store password:

> Don't automatically restore purchases, especially when your app is launched. Restoring purchases prompts for the user’s App Store credentials, which interrupts the flow of your app.

I tried quite a few apps but never observed this behavior. One example is [bear](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/bear/id1016366447), a freemium note taking app. When I pressed its "restore purchase" button, it just went ahead to query and then showed an alert saying that there was no purchase information for me.

I wonder how is this implemented? I guess it stores users purchase information on its own server so it queries its own server, instead of App store. **But the question is how it identifies me?** (Note Bear app doesn't require user to create an account to use the app. I just downloaded the app and didn't do anything in it yet.). I know iOS has DeviceCheck API, but I think that only identifies a device, instead of an user, right?

Thanks for any help.

Note: Bear app's "restore purchase" button can be found by going to its side menu, pressing setting button at the bottom, pressing "get Pro!" button.

Comment: I'm not sure but I suppose they identify it based on iCloud account.

Comment: Given the few discussion I found on the net (I don't know iCloud programming details well enough yet), I think you might be right. Thanks. But if so, what if an user doesn't enable iCloud? BTW, when I tested this in those apps, I wasn't prompted to give iCloud permission to them (it might be that accessing the ID doesn't need that permission. I'm not sure).

Comment: You need to be signed in with Apple ID in order to download apps and make purchases, when you open App Store and click on your account you can see there is your apple id logged, thats how they do it. Also you can see your purchase history etc. there. So not iCloud but Apple ID account is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be signed in with Apple ID in order to download apps and make purchases, that's how they match it.

Comment: I'm afraid you perhaps misunderstood what I asked. The apps I tested are all freemium apps (free + IAP). Of course I need to log in my Apple ID to download them, but that is not visible to those apps. What I'm asking is the restoreCompletedTransactions() call. I think it prompts user to authenticate, doesn't it? But when I tested those apps, I wasn't prompted for authentication.

Comment: All those apps with purchases are using StoreKit API which somehow communicate with App Store. All this handling of this purchase authentication etc. is not handled by app itself but by system. IMO you wasn't prompt for authentication because you were already logged in something that they require - App Store

Comment: Hmm...I'm not sure. iOS does re-athenticate user in some cases. I'll do more experiments and check around and get back to you on this. Thanks.